# PayPal IPN Simulator Custom Text Fields

Tags: php, paypal, textfield, paypal-ipn, simulator

I have the following PayPal button set up:

```
   <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
       <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
       <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SN3834XQZMRCW">
       <table>
           <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Minecraft Username:">Minecraft Username:</td></tr>
           <tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
           <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="TeamSpeak UID:">TeamSpeak UID:</td></tr>
           <tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
       </table>
       <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
       <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
   </form>
```

According to the documentation, the two hidden fields I have simply get passed to PayPal and then back to my PHP script. To get these values, would it be correct to use the following:

```
$_POST['TeamSpeak UID:'];
```

Before you ask, I can't seem to send these custom fields using the simulator, unless the fields are encapsulated within the custom field? The documentation and help seems to be lacking here. Thanks for any help.